# cross compile qt 5.2

Tags: raspbian, cross-compilation, qt

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.ics.com/blog/building-qt-and-qtwayland-raspberry-pi#.UzQoqtvMfeQ) to cross compile qt 5.2. But I'm getting this error:

```
You have already accepted the terms of the  license.
    /home/vitor/src/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    /home/vitor/src/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -fvisibility=hidden fvisibility.c
    /home/vitor/src/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Symbol visibility control disabled.
    -reduce-exports was requested but this compiler does not support it
    Re-run configure with -v for more information
```

So, I have to install the libstdc++ on host or target?!
With a locate libstdc++ I found libstdc in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

how can I indicate the correct location?

Comment: the comment here http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=19070&p=195239 states you can remove the flag and just continue

Comment: I'm with another (in open gl es 2.0) error https://gist.github.com/vitorcarvalhoml/9811837